# JAAS auth kerberos error "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out"

Tags: kerberos, jaas

i have installed a kerberos server.

```html
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = SNSPRJ.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
# EXAMPLE.COM = {
#  kdc = kerberos.example.com
#  admin_server = kerberos.example.com
# }
  SNSPRJ.COM = {
    kdc = kerberos.snsprj.com
    admin_server = kerberos.snsprj.com
  }


[domain_realm]
# .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
# example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
  .snsprj.com = SNSPRJ.COM
  snsprj.com = SNSPRJ.COM
```

```html
[kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 88
 kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
 SNSPRJ.COM = {
  #master_key_type = aes256-cts
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal arcfour-hmac:normal camellia256-cts:normal camellia128-cts:normal des-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-md5:normal des-cbc-crc:normal
 }
~
```

In the kerberos client ,i use kinit xiaoxiao/admin@SNSPRJ.COM and it's see ok

```html
[root@bogon ~]# kinit xiaoxiao/admin@SNSPRJ.COM
Password for xiaoxiao/admin@SNSPRJ.COM: 
[root@bogon ~]# klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: xiaoxiao/admin@SNSPRJ.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
08/24/2017 13:51:18  08/25/2017 13:51:17  krbtgt/SNSPRJ.COM@SNSPRJ.COM
[root@bogon ~]#
```

but when i use JAAS to auth kerberos server some error message occur :
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out

i have tey telnet 192.168.1.196 88 it's ok.

```html
bogon:jaas0822 skh$ telnet 192.168.1.196 88
Trying 192.168.1.196...
Connected to bogon.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

JAAS Authentication:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html

my code:

```html
import javax.security.auth.login.*;
import com.sun.security.auth.callback.TextCallbackHandler;

/**
 * This JaasAcn application attempts to authenticate a user
 * and reports whether or not the authentication was successful.
 *
 * Created by skh on 2017/8/22.
 */
public class JaasAcn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "/workspace/idea/ssm/src/test/java/com/snsprj/jaas0822/";

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", path + "jaas.conf");

//        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", path + "krb5.conf");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "SNSPRJ.COM");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "kerberos.snsprj.com");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug", "true");

        // Obtain a LoginContext, needed for authentication. Tell it
        // to use the LoginModule implementation specified by the
        // entry named "JaasSample" in the JAAS login configuration
        // file and to also use the specified CallbackHandler.
        LoginContext lc = null;
        try {
            lc = new LoginContext("JaasSample", new TextCallbackHandler());

            // attempt authentication
            try {
                lc.login();
            } catch (LoginException le) {
                le.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Authentication failed:");
                System.err.println("  " + le.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        } catch (LoginException le) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create LoginContext. " + le.getMessage());

        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create LoginContext. " + se.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Authentication succeeded!");

    }
}
```

is something worry? anyone can help me ,think you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Solution :use TCP

```html
[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = SNSPRJ.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
 # insert by xiaohb 20170824 start
 udp_preference_limit = 1
 # insert by xiaohb 20170824 end
```